# Can I insert a vector to itself with std::vector::insert?

Tags: c++, stdvector, c++03

Is it allowed by the C++03 standard to append a `std::vector` to itself? I wonder if the source iterators can become invalid if `v` needs to reallocate memory. In my STL implementation, the old memory is kept until the new memory has been created. But can I rely on this? If not, is `v.reserve(2 * v.size())` before the insert a good solution to avoid the reallocation altogether?

```
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(3);
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
// v may need to reallocate because its capacity may be less than 6.
// Is this operation safe?
v.insert(v.end(), v.cbegin(), v.cend());
```

or

```
// Here v will _not_ need to reallocate because it has enough capacity.
// Is this operation safe?
v.reserve(2 * v.size());
v.insert(v.end(), v.cbegin(), v.cend());
```

Comment: Please see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless of whether perform `reserve` in advance or not, the behavior is undefined. For [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert):

> inserts elements from range [first, last) before pos.
>
> The behavior is undefined if first and last are iterators into `*this`.

Comment: How would you achieve the goal then? Is there a clean alternative?

Comment: @Fabian You may loop and `push_back` manually, with `reserve` in advance. Or copy the elements to a new `vector`, then `insert` them back.

Comment: What about resize() + std::copy()? Or reserve() + std::copy() with back_inserter?

Comment: @Fabian I think it's fine. For the latter one, you need to use the end iterator carefully because it'll become invalid in the process of inserting.